# How to format my UPDATE statement correctly? Getting not unique table/alias error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am getting a "... not unique table/alias 'plots' ..." error when trying to run the following UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE homestead.plots
INNER JOIN homestead.graphs
    ON homestead.drivers.id = homestead.graphs.driver_id
INNER JOIN homestead.plots 
    ON homestead.plots.graph_id = homestead.graphs.id 
SET homestead.plots.yAxis = homestead.plots.yAxis + 3.4
WHERE homestead.graphs.name = "DI";
```

Even though the below SELECT statement works fine, and returns the results I want:

```
SELECT homestead.graphs.driver_id, homestead.drivers.MarketingNo, homestead.graphs.name, homestead.plots.xAxis, homestead.plots.yAxis 
FROM homestead.drivers
INNER JOIN homestead.graphs
    ON homestead.drivers.id = homestead.graphs.driver_id
INNER JOIN homestead.plots 
    ON homestead.plots.graph_id = homestead.graphs.id 
WHERE homestead.graphs.name = "DI";
```

Any ideas how to fix my UPDATE statement to work? I've done a lot of research online but cannot understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flaws with your `UPDATE` statement, for example:

- table `plots` is referenced twice (in the `UPDATE` and in a `JOIN`) and not aliased (this is causing the error that you are getting)
- you are referring to column `id` in table `homestead.graphs`, but this table is not part of any join

Based on your `SELECT` query, I would try and phrase your `UPDATE` as follows:

```
UPDATE homestead.plots p
INNER JOIN homestead.graphs g  ON p.graph_id = g.id AND g.name = "DI"
INNER JOIN homestead.drivers d ON d.id = g.driver_id
SET p.yAxis = p.yAxis + 3.4
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I sometimes have a hard time wrapping my head around how to phrase UPDATE statements since the syntax isn't quite as obviously "logical" to me as SELECT statements.

Comment: Welcome @Matt! Happy to help.